# how do I set time limits for individual threads in a thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading

how do I set time limits for individual threads in a thread pool..? 
The parent thread need not wait until every thread finishes and returns back. Instead it should fetch the next job(runnable/callable) and submit to the thread pool...

Comment: Does the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819855/time-limit-on-individual-threads-with-executorservice help?

Answer (score 0):

More context would be useful.

You might try using `ExecutorCompletionService`:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a task to the same pool, or another one which will cancel the first task after a given amount of time. If it has completed this does nothing.