# Putting a time out on individual threads inside ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am using the threadPoolExecutor class from the java api to handle all my threads. At the moment i have 5 threads that can exist in the thread pool. My threads are all doing the same task. They are doing a requests to the database and they wait for a reply. Some times the database does not reply for some time. This means these threads get stuck in the thread pool waiting.

I was wondering was there any way to set a time out on threads in the thread pool. so if a thread is running for more than half an hour then the thread pool will kill it and process the next thread in the queue. I do not

At the moment the threads inside the thread pool have their own timer task that writes to a log saying the thread is taking more than 30 minutes. I am trying to think of a way of killing off threads that take this long.

How can I do that !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time limit on individual threads with ExecutorService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819855/time-limit-on-individual-threads-with-executorservice)

Answer (score 1):

> Keep-alive times
>
> If the pool currently has more than corePoolSize threads, excess
>   threads will be terminated if they have been idle for more than the
>   keepAliveTime (see getKeepAliveTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).
>   This provides a means of reducing resource consumption when the pool
>   is not being actively used. If the pool becomes more active later, new
>   threads will be constructed. This parameter can also be changed
>   dynamically using method setKeepAliveTime(long,
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit). Using a value of Long.MAX_VALUE
>   TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS effectively disables idle threads from ever
>   terminating prior to shut down. By default, the keep-alive policy
>   applies only when there are more than corePoolSizeThreads. But method
>   allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean) can be used to apply this time-out
>   policy to core threads as well, so long as the keepAliveTime value is
>   non-zero.

From the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowsCoreThreadTimeOut%28%29) Java docs

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `CachedThreadPool`.

**2.** CachedThreadPool will pool, will be starting of with defined number of threads. Now depending of the necessity it can span new thread.

**3.** Most **amazing and your desired feature** of `CachedThreadPool` is that, **when a thread is not involved in any activity for 60 seconds, then it is killed.**