# Is there a solution for an ExecutorService that time limits each submitted Callable

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

Here is what I have... I have a list of tasks that will each be submitted on its own `ExecutorService`. I want each task to have a time limit of x MS after it has **started execution**. I have seen solutions like the one posted at [Time Limit on Individual Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819855/time-limit-on-individual-threads-with-executorservice) but this puts a time limit starting on when the task was submitted.

I thought one solution would an extension to the accepted solution to [Time Limit on Individual Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819855/time-limit-on-individual-threads-with-executorservice). This would wrap the `Callable` in another `Callable` that would put the cancel task on the scheduled executor once it has started. This would involve a mapping of the `Callable` to the `Future` in an non-trivial manner so I thought I would post to see if anyone knows of an existing solution (code re-use being a wonderful thing and all).

Thanks.

As an FYI, the solution posted at [Time Limit on Individual Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819855/time-limit-on-individual-threads-with-executorservice) is the following. Again this cancels from submit time, not start time:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
ScheduledExecutorService canceller = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public <T> Future<T> executeTask(Callable<T> c, long timeoutMS){
   final Future<T> future = service.submit(c);
   canceller.schedule(new Callable<Void>(){
       public Void call(){
          future.cancel(true);
          return null;
       }
    }, timeoutMS, TimeUnit.MILLI_SECONDS);
   return future;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look if this works for you.

Sorry if the code is messy, but it is just to demonstrate the concept: pass back the future to the task, let the task start its own timer - the timer will start when the task start.

The following code adds 10 tasks, each takes 2 seconds to execute but the timeout is in 1 second.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CancellableTaskDemo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new CancellableTaskDemo();
    }

    final ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public CancellableTaskDemo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int c = i;
            submitTask(new Callable<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    final long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        System.out.println("Task " + c + " done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + "ms");
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Task " + c + " aborted after " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + "ms");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        ex.shutdown();
        try {
            ex.awaitTermination(100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void submitTask(final Callable<Object> c, final int timeout) {
        final TimedFutureTask tft = new TimedFutureTask(c, timeout);
        final Future<?> ft = ex.submit(tft.getCallable());
        tft.setFuture(ft);
    }

    static class TimedFutureTask {
        final static ScheduledExecutorService canceller = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        private Timer cancelTimer;
        private Callable<Object> timedCallable;
        private Future<?> f;
        private int timeoutMS;

        public TimedFutureTask(final Callable<Object> callable, final int timeoutMS) {
            this.timeoutMS = timeoutMS;
            timedCallable = (new Callable<Object>() {

                @Override
                public Object call() throws Exception {

                    cancelTimer = new Timer();
                    cancelTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            f.cancel(true);

                        }
                    }, timeoutMS);

                    final Object res = callable.call();
                    cancelTimer.cancel();
                    return res;
                }

            });
        }

        public Callable<Object> getCallable() {
            return timedCallable;
        }

        public void setFuture(final Future<?> future) {
            f = future;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 This is a great example implementation of what I believe to be the solution. It will probably be what I use. However, The purpose of the post was to see if there was an existing library / JDK mechanism to do this.

Comment: I maintain several open source projects on SourceForge.net. One of them is probably what you are looking for. This article is about the embarrassingly parallel project:  [Fork-Join Development in Java SE](http://http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/ForkJoinArticle.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ScheduleExecutorService.

```
final Future future = es.submit(myTask);
ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        future.cancel(true);
    }
}, timeout, timeUnit);
```

Comment: As I state in my post, this solution cancels the task `timeout` from when it is submitted not `timeout` from when it starts execution.

Comment: Link in the question refers to same answer of yours only :)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no simple way to do this because the Callable could be started before the Future is returned.  You can wrap this in Callable on the assumption that once this is run it will be callable will be run soon after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually but its too much of a code to do a simple task :(

```
public void run() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long timeout = 60 * 1000;
    do {
        // Do work here
    } while (TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - start,
            TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            - start > timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the timer as part of the task you submit, so it will start when the task is executed. just, in this case, you cannot use future.cancel but you can interrupt the thread.Depending on the tasks you submit terminating gracefully and in a timely fashion can be easy or not.

Comment: This would mean that the Callable to have to implement this itself and check the timer throughout the code.

Comment: You can build a wrapper around the submit to embed the code automatically, I will post an example later

Comment: This would then block on the submit call preventing the caller from submitting multiple callables and waiting for them all to complete.