# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: execution timeout

Tags: multithreading, spring, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Is there a way to set timeout on exectution of task submitted to *ThreadPoolTaskExecutor*? Otherwise it's possible that pool is wasted on hanged tasks which effectively paralyzes the application.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819855/time-limit-on-individual-threads-with-executorservice and work out similar to what is mentioned in this post?

Comment: check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout

Answer (score 2):

In short **NO**.

However there is an [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-long-) `execute(Runnable task, long startTimeout)` which has a timeout to indicate the start / execution of task.

Comment: The problem is that the implementation of this method is:  public void execute(Runnable task, long startTimeout) {
        this.execute(task);
    }